Unable to lock row or deadlock issue
We have over 200 test methods in the org and since I started creating some test classes for my own Sandbox I have ran into issues with the following error but may vary by method:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record: [] Class.CaseCommentControllerTest.testSaveCommentWithWrongUserId: line 144, column 1
Sometimes it all runs fine and sometimes I get the System.DmlException. However another issue is probably related to the deadlock concept. Basically the testclasses tries to run for 10-20 minutes before the first one completes, and I can't find where the problem is. I tried removing all of the new tests I created but still facing the same issues, which was not there before afaik.
Here is an example of the code it complains on:
User otherUser = TestDataFactory.getSysAdminUser();
insert otherUser;


Deadlocks happen in unit tests when you use shared resources, such as Custom Settings, because while unit tests are isolated from production data, they aren't isolated from each other.
Sometimes it's possible to redesign your tests to use fewer shared resources, thus avoid potential deadlocks (e.g. don't create records you don't need, or use different names for shared resources), but this is circumstantial and often difficult to engineer around efficiently.
You'll want to disable parallel unit testing (Setup | Custom Code | Apex Test Execution | Options... | Disable Parallel Apex Testing). This will increase run time, but avoid deadlocks that would otherwise occur. You can use @isTest(IsParallel=true) to enable tests that don't deadlock to run in parallel.

Thanks for your answer. I found two methods which seems to lock everything, disabling those makes all of the test classes in the org run successfully, however the time it takes varies a lot (not sure why?) Another question: Running in the IDE (Intellij) vs running on the browser is largely different, where the browser runs quicker using the same settings. Is this related to memory limit in the IDE?

@MrKnudz (a) Salesforce is a shared resource, so execution time depends on system load. (b) The Developer Console uses the Tooling API, while IDEs use the Metadata API. The Tooling API is better suited for fast development, the Metadata API for deployments to various orgs (particularly production orgs).
